# Das Team rauft sich schnell zusammen

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Das Team rauft sich schnell zusammen.

What does "sich raufen" in this context mean? Does it mean fight with each others?

Comment: Did you try looking it up in a dictionary? Hint: look under *zusammenraufen*.

Comment: you mean it is a separable verb? zusammenraufen? I will look

Comment: For example *Duden* has it. But the other dictionaries too, of course. - Yes, it is separable. *Wir raufen uns zusammen. / Wir werden uns zusammenraufen.*

Answer (score 4):

> Does it mean fight with each others?

Yes, it means to fight and argue, but in the end get to an agreement. The adjective *zusammen* emphazises this as the final result for a team.

Here's a more "official" reference:

https://www.dwds.de/wb/zusammenraufen

> > Menschen gegensätzlicher Meinung kommen nach anfänglichen heftigen Auseinandersetzungen schließlich zu einer Übereinstimmung

Note that the term is considered *colloquial*.

Comment: „Zusammenraufen“ happens _after_ the fighting, so no, they don’t fight with each other.

Comment: @lejonet The fighting and arguing is part of the whole process.